# KnockoutJS losing the viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble with a proof of concept. What I'm trying do is have a jQuery dialog come up when a button is clicked. The dialog contents are bound to a viewmodel and the dialog calls a a json service to retrieve some data to populate that viewmodel.

Running into two problems with the code I have here:

- The vmAccount viewmodel will only bind if the div is visible from the initial page load
- The vmAccount viewmodel is undefined in either SearchForCustomerAccounts or in DisplayResults despite being a global var to those

```js
$(function() {

  var vmAccount = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.Accounts = ko.observableArray();
    this.Name = ko.observable('Jimmy');
  };

  function DisplayDialog() {

    $("#Dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Search": function() {
          SearchForCustomerAccounts();

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function SearchForCustomerAccounts() {
    console.log("Name: " + vmAccount.Name);
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/CustomerSearchController/" + vmAccount.Name,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        DisplayResults(data);
      }
    });
  }

  function DisplayResults(data) {
    vmAccount.Accounts.removeAll();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      vmAccount.Accounts.push(data[i]);
    }
  };

  $("#butSearch").button().on("click", function() {
    DisplayDialog();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vmAccount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="butSearch">Open</button>

  <div id="Dialog" style="visibility: visible">
    <form id="Account">
      <p>Customer Name</p>
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

I'm new to javascript and knockout so its probably something simple thats missing. Appreciate any help you guys can provide, thanks!

Comment: Your code snippet is missing jQuery UI

Comment: Whoops forgot to add in that reference using stackoverflow coding snippet tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your `vmAccount` is function, but you try to use it like instance.

2) To get value from KO's observable, you should call it (unwrap value).
So use `vmAccount.Name()` instead of `vmAccount.Name`.

```js
$(function() {

  function VmAccount () {
    var self = this;
    this.Accounts = ko.observableArray();
    this.Name = ko.observable('Jimmy');
  };
  
  var vmAccount = new VmAccount();

  function DisplayDialog() {

    $("#Dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Search": function() {
          SearchForCustomerAccounts();

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function SearchForCustomerAccounts() {
    console.log("Name: " + vmAccount.Name());
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/CustomerSearchController/" + vmAccount.Name(),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        DisplayResults(data);
      }
    });
  }

  function DisplayResults(data) {
    vmAccount.Accounts.removeAll();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      vmAccount.Accounts.push(data[i]);
    }
  };

  $("#butSearch").button().on("click", function() {
    DisplayDialog();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vmAccount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="butSearch">Open</button>

  <div id="Dialog" style="visibility: visible">
    <form id="Account">
      <p>Customer Name</p>
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick with the second issue thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The code should look some thing like this, vmAccount is empty because the function is not returning anything;

```
var vmAccount = function() {
var self = this;
this.Accounts = ko.observableArray();
this.Name = ko.observable('Jimmy');
return this;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  var vmAccount = {
    Accounts : ko.observableArray(),
    Name : ko.observable('Jimmy'),
  };

  function DisplayDialog() {

    $("#Dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Search": function() {
          SearchForCustomerAccounts();

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function SearchForCustomerAccounts() {
    console.log("Name: " + vmAccount.Name());
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/CustomerSearchController/" + vmAccount.Name(),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        DisplayResults(data);
      }
    });
  }

  function DisplayResults(data) {
    vmAccount.Accounts.removeAll();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      vmAccount.Accounts.push(data[i]);
    }
  };

  $("#butSearch").button().on("click", function() {
    DisplayDialog();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vmAccount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="butSearch">Open</button>

  <div id="Dialog" style="visibility: visible">
    <form id="Account">
      <p>Customer Name</p>
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name()" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```